# get promise for keyboard response

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show an image on the screen. As soon as the image is displayed, the user should be able to press a key. I didn't figure out yet how to allow the press of a key only if the image has been displayed already. I came across Promises but I don't know how to use them for my specific problem. So the function which displays the image should be fulfilled before the function for a keyboard response is enabled.

```
<div id='area'>
<div id="div"></div>
</div>
<button id="Button" onclick="start();"> Go </button>
```

Javascript:

```
function display_image(){
$('#div').addClass("circle");
}

function keyboard_response(){
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
alert("key pressed");
};
}

function start(){
display_image();
keyboard_response();
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bV9A/6/

As soon as the "Go"-Button is pressed, the picture should be displayed. Afterwards, the keyboard_response() function should work. Here, it doesn't make a huge difference because it doesn't take time to show the image ,but imagine I want to show more pictures and it takes say 500ms. During this time, no key press should be possible.

Comment: Include jQuery in jsFiddle and don't wrap code in load handler, here is your fixed jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6bV9A/6/  Indeed, your code is correct

Comment: thanks, I edited my question and used your fiddle.

Comment: But be aware,  javascript is single thread language so if no async method is used, your code will work as expected. If loading some images and you want to wait for them to be fully loaded, then use onload event relative to all these images and set logic regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

**[This](http://jsbin.com/wehas/2/edit)** is a solution using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
$(function(){
  var customName = 'my_events';
  var display_image = function(){
    var img = $('<img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">');
    $('#area').append(img);
    img.on('load.'+customName, keyboard_response);
  };
  var keyboard_response = function (){
    $(document).on('keydown.'+customName, function(e) {
      alert("key pressed:" + e.which);
    });
  };
  $('#go').on('click.'+customName, display_image);
});
```

The reason I'm using jQuery is because it provides cross browser support.
The "my_events" string makes easy for you to remove events later using ["off"](http://api.jquery.com/off/) method